# Assigning Class To Copy Of object in constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, constructor, instantiation

How do I use a method that returns the correct object type to assign it as the Class object. I can Write code that explains my question better I think.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooNumer = 0;

    public Foo()
    { 
        this = FooGenerator.GetNewFoo(); //Does not work, is read only
    }
}

public static class FooGenerator()
{
  public static Foo GetNewFoo()
  {
    return new Foo(){FooNumer = 1};
  }
}
```

I want the new Foo Cass I instantiated, to be a copy of the object coming from FooGenerator.

this is readonly, hence the above code will not work. Is there a simple solution, is this possible, am I overlooking something stupid?

EDIT:

Adding additional psuedo-code to explain my purpose better.

```
public class FooBase
{
    public string FooNumer = 0;
    public string Type;
    public string Count;
    public string Creator;

    public FooBase()
    {

    }

    public FooBase(DataSet ds)
    {
        FooNumer = ds.Rows[0]["Number"];
        Type =  ds.Rows[0]["Type"];
        Count =  ds.Rows[0]["Count"];
        Creator =  ds.Rows[0]["Creator"];
    }

    public FooBase(int id)
    { 
        this = FooDAL.GetFooFromDatabase(id);
    }
}

public class FooDAL
{
    public static GetFooFromDatabase(int fooID)
    {
        DataSet data = GetDataSetFromDatabase(fooID);

        return new FooBase(data);
    }
}

public class FooBaby : FooBase
{
    public string BabyWeight;

     FooBaby(int id) :
         base(id)
    {
        //Now by using this constructor, all the properties of FooBaby base(FooBase) will be instantiated in the base constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to implement the singleton pattern...

Comment: @RonBeyer I dont think i do...? FooGenerator really pulls an item from a database based on the number you sent in, i just simplieified it here.

Comment: You can't reassign `this` int he constructor (or anywhere else).  It sounds like you already have a factory method, so making the `Foo` constructor internal should force clients to use the factory method.  If there's a reason you don;t want to do that then edit your question.

Comment: @DStanley I understand I cant assign to this. The reason Is now I have a FooBaby that inherits from Foo, and needs to use to be created using the constructor from Foo.

Comment: You want the parent class to create a derived class?  That seems backwards.  Perhaps you should add the pseudo-code for `FooBaby` as well?

Comment: @DStanley - no, seems, he wants the base class to initialize its fields/properties from those of the instance returned by `FooGenerator`.

Comment: @DStanley I am creating a wrapper to allow our objects to be easier to use. I will add some more psudo-code. I looked over FlyWeight Factory, it seems...kind of close. give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Igor essentially yes, that sounds correct. FooGenerator has a TON of legacy field, properties, and crap that I am trying to simplify. Instead of recreating logic, I'd wrather use the logic provided in the base classes.

Comment: @CalvinSmith - consider using reflection for copying field/property values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copy constructor`

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooNumer = 0;

    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(Foo copyFrom)
    {
        this.FooNumer = copyFrom.FooNumer;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo(FooGenerator().GetNewFoo());
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but its a class with alot of properties, so thats kind of a last resort

Answer (score 0):

> FooGenerator really pulls an item from a database based on the number you sent in

This sounds like a `Flyweight Factory`.  You could implement something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooNumber {get;}

    internal Foo(int fooNumber)  // internal so only clients within the same assembly can use it
    { 
        FooNumber = fooNumber;
    }
}

public static class FooGenerator()
{
  public static Dictionary<int, Foo> instances = new Dictionary<int, Foo>();

  public static Foo GetFoo(int fooNumber)
  {
    if(!instances.ContainsKey(fooNumber))
       // this Foo has not yet been created, so create and add it
       instances.Add(fooNumber,new Foo(fooNumber));
  }

  // pull the Foo from the list by fooNumber
  return instances[fooNumber];
}
```